# Elasticsearch ranges in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to execute this query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) :

```
{
    "range" : {
        "age" : {
            "gte" : 10,
            "lte" : 20
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this code:

```
QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("age").gte(10).lte(20)
```

but generates this other query:

```
{
  "range" : {
    "age" : {
      "from" : 10,
      "to" : 20,
      "include_lower" : true,
      "include_upper" : true
    }
  }
}
```

**How to create the range like in the documentation using the Java API?** I think that "from" and "to" are deprecated from version 0.98.

The problem is when I try to execute this other query:

```
{
    "range" : {
        "age" : {
            "gte" : 10
        }
    }
}
```

Because this code :

```
QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("age").gte(10)
```

Generate this other query:

```
{
  "range" : {
    "age" : {
      "from" : 10,
      "to" : null,
      "include_lower" : true,
      "include_upper" : true
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, the same problem plus that "to" is null.
**Again, how to create this simple query using the Java API?**

Anyway, To use "from" and "to" instead of "gte" or "lte" returns the same result. Only, I am concerned about a possible misunderstand of the documentation or a BUG in the Java API.

**Environment:**

- Java 8
- ElasticSearch 2.2.1
- ElasticSearch Java API 2.2.0

Comment: That syntax is still perfectly valid. There must be a reason why the ES folks kept it around, but I wouldn't worry too much about it as long as it works.

Comment: @Val So it is valid, but maybe is good idea update the Java API to be align with the documentation and new syntax, right?

Comment: Yes, you can feel free to raise a bug, or even submit a patch.